# Java docx4j Bold Text

Tags: java, ms-word, openxml, wordprocessingml, docx4j

I do a search and replace on a word document by using docx4j and the following code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(pathFinder.findUploadPath() + filename));

        //Get all text elements out of the doc
        List texts = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath(XPATH_TO_SELECT_TEXT_NODES, true);

        // Loop through all "text" elements
        for (Object obj : texts) {
            Text text = (Text) ((JAXBElement) obj).getValue(); //get the value of the object

            // Get the string value
            String textValueBefore = text.getValue();

            text.setValue(string_afterwards);
        }
```

The "string_afterwards" is a generated string by some other code lines.

My problem is, to format this string, so that it will appear in **bold** style.
Is there any chance to do it, without changing the search&replace lines?
Something like to add a tag < b > to the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change XPATH_TO_SELECT_TEXT_NODES so it selects the parent w:r element of the text nodes of interest.

Then make sure the w:r has a w:rPr (run properties element), and set that to bold.